# How do I use a Regex to replace non-alphanumeric characters with white space?

Tags: javascript

I built a Javascript function to make the first letter uppercase. My issue is that I have some words which are like "name_something" and what I want is "Name Something".

I did this:

```
function toCamelCase(text) {
  return text.replace(/\b(\w)/g, function (match, capture) {
    return capture.toUpperCase();
  }).split(/[^a-zA-Z]/);
}
```

Comment: So, what went wrong? What is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `[\W_]` to get rid of characters that are not alphanumeric. Where `W` represent characters from `a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9`

```js
var str = 'this $is a _test@#$%';
str = str.replace(/[\W_]+/g,' ');
console.log(str);
```

So, to make the words capitalise alongside the replace you can do,

```js
var str = 'this $is a _test@#$%';
str = str.replace(/[\W_]+/g,' ');
var res = str.split(' ').map((s) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substr(1)).join(' ');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks could you please show me in my case how that will be?
I have some issues to adapt it to my

Comment: @Jakub check the working snippet. The second one replaces and change to uppercase